# Want to add multiple excel stream into single pdf file

Tags: java, apache-poi

Want to add multiple excel stream into single pdf file. I have byte stream of excel and want append into on pdf file.
I did it but only one excel stream is genrated.

Comment: "I did it but only one excel stream is generated.": What exactly have you tried? Please show your code.

Comment: Actully I have multiple exce stream . I want to add all of them into one pdf file